# Return a certain value from a table

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

[TABLE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSyR4.png)

[TABLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Zrk.png)

Hi guys , might be a bit ''noob'' in terms of excel and the way i explain everything but here we go :

I've been messing around with Vlookup , index and match functions ( I'm not a pro with excel , just trying to ease my job , so far google helped me and made a lot of things, but this particular one I can't really see it through , hope someone can help.

So on Table 1 everything will stay the same except the REG , VAN , provider , Model that will change on a daily basis.

On Table 2 in D2 cell i want to return the value from Table1 (Driver's name of who is assigned that registration number ).

Reason for that is i have around 150 entries , and sometimes i need for random checks around 10-15, and (ctr+f , copy , paste , create another table is time consuming )

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the table data was not available, I created a few columns to demonstate what you would need to do.

VLOOKUP will not work as it expects the lookup value to be in the first column.

I have used the Index/match and it works fine. You can use similar one changing the column names to the correct columns in your sheet. Note that `TABLE1` in in `Sheet1` and `TABLE2` is in `Sheet2` of the same excel workbook in my example.

For the `TABLE2 - DRIVER` column, you need the formula as `=INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A6,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!C2:C6,0))` and you can drag the cell down so that all rows are correctly identified. In Sheet1/TABLE1 - DRIVER is in column A and REG is in column C. In Sheet2/TABLE 2, REG is in column A. There is one header and 5 rows of data, so the values are from  `C2:C6` and `A2:A6` . If you have more rows, you will need to change accordingly. Let me know if you face issues. Also attaching the two tables so you can relate.

[image: Sheet1 TABLE1]   [image: Sheet2 TABLE2]